# Need help with binding Telerik's RADStrip dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

Followed **[this](http://mono.telerik.com/TabStrip/Examples/PopulatingWithData/DynamicCreation/DefaultCS.aspx)** example on telerik's website and implemented as follows:-

aspx page:-

```
<div id="div1" runat="server">
        <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStrip1" runat="server" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1">
        </telerik:RadTabStrip>
        <telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage1" runat="server" Width="100%">
            <telerik:RadPageView ID="pv1" runat="server" Selected="true">
            </telerik:RadPageView>
        </telerik:RadMultiPage>
    </div>
```

code behind:-

This method in the line dataset ds = objbllQuesType.GetQuesType(); returns a DataSet with a table containing QuesTypeID and QuesType's Name

Now what is happening is, only 4 Tabs are being generated on the RadStrip which I know is coz of the "for loop (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)"
I want the no. of tabs to be equal to the no. of QuesType s I have in my Table which is 6.

Also , ALL the tabs' Text is "QuesType1" when it should be as follows:-

In the RadStrip, Tab1's Text should be "QuesType1", Tab2's Text should be "QuesType2" , Tab3's Text should be "QuesType3" and so on.

How should I modify the code above to achieve what I want ?

**[EDIT]
Has anyone worked with Telerik's RADStrip? Need help plz.**

What should I change in the code below so it fetches the QuesTypes and binds QuesTypes to the tabs ? Currently its only fetching 1st QuesType and binding that one to ALL the tab's text attribute.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
            tab.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["QuesType"].ToString();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code for set text to tabs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataSet ds = GetDataSet();

            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                CreateRootTab(i, ds);
            }
            RadTabStrip1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    private void CreateRootTab(int index, DataSet ds)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            var tab = new RadTab();
            tab.Text = (string) ds.Tables[0].Rows[index].ItemArray[i];
            RadTabStrip1.Tabs.Add(tab);
        }
    }

    private DataSet GetDataSet()
    {
        bllQuesType objbllQuesQType = new bllQuesType();
        var ds = new DataSet();
        return objbllQuesType.GetQuesType();
    }
```

I didn't work with Rad, but I think it can be helpfull in your case.

Best regards, Dima.

Comment: In the code above , GetQuesType() returns a complete QuesType named Table so the Tabs generated by the code below are like equal to the no. of records in the table. What I want is that ONLY QuesType column be binded to the Tabs. What should I change in this code?

Comment: If you have to bind column called QuesType, you need to go through each row and get column you want. Try this:    for(int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++ ){tab.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["QuesType"];} Hope it will help )